SQL Macro to store date list
I have to use a SAS macro within a WHERE condition in a PROC SQL statement.
The SAS macro needs to hold a list of dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd, like this:
2023-01-03 
2024-04-06 
2024-02-02


DATA datas; 
INFILE DATALINES DLM='|';
Input enddate:yymmdd10.;
datalines;
2023-11-16
2023-12-01
;
RUN;

DATA datas1; SET datas; FORMAT enddate yymmdd10.;RUN;

PROC SQL;
SELECT enddate INTO: enddate FROM datas1;
QUIT;
%PUT enddate is &enddate;

PROC SQL;
CONNECT TO TERDATA AS db(SERVER ='' USER="" PWD="" MODE=TERDATA);
CREATE TABLE ad.CURTEMP_file AS
SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO db
( SELECT a,b,c FROM db.table1 );
DISCONNECT FROM db
QUIT;

PROC SQL;
CONNECT TO TERADATA AS db(SERVER='' USER="" PWD="" MODE=TERADATA);
CREATE TABLE as.YESTTEMP_file AS
SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO db
( SELECT c.a, c.b, c.c, i.a, i.b, i.c, i.DATE_AS_OF_DATE
FROM db.table2 i INNER JOIN ad.CURTEMP_file c ON i.a=c.b                 
AND i.DATA_AS_OF_DATE = '2024-01-25'); DISCONNECT FROM db QUIT;

I need to use the macro &enddate in place of '2024-01-25'. This returns a table which 0 records

Do you mean a macro variable?  Where are the values supposed to come from?  Can't you just type them into a %LET statement?

Before you try to use the macro language to generate code you need know what code you want generate.  Whether it is via running a macro or just expanding the value of a macro variable.  So show the code that works without any macro language syntax.  Explain what parts needs to be generated.  Explain the source for the part that needs to be generated.

I want to store a list of dates in a SAS macro so that I can use it in a SQL statement in a WHERE condition.   Dates needs to be in the format : 2023-01-03 , 2023-04-06, 2023-02-02.

Show code that works without any macro language. Then someone can show how to use the macro language to create it. Note that SAS will not recognize 2023-02-02 as a date. To SAS that text is a numeric expression that evaluates to 2023.

DATA datas; INFILE DATALINES DLM='|';  Input enddate:yymmdd10.;

Is DATAS the dataset you want to query? Is ENDATE teh variable you want to filter on?
If you want to query ENDDATE then use SAS date literals, such as '03JAN2023'd  or the actual integer values used to represent those dates.

Show an example of using one (or more) date values in a WHERE statement or SQL WHERE clause.  Once you get that syntax to work then you will know what text you need to put into the macro variable (or text you want a macro to emit if you are actually planning to use %MACRO statement to define a macro) to replace the list of hardcoded dates in your example.

So you need to generate SQL code for some other database system to use?  If you want the text '2023-01-25' in the macro variable then don't forget to include the ' characters.

To select a list of values you probably will want to use the IN operator.  In SAS code that would look like this:
data want;
  set have;
  where enddate in ('03JAN2023'd '04MAY2023'd);
run;

Or the same in SQL code:
proc sql;
  create table want as select * from have
    where enddate in ('03JAN2023'd '04MAY2023'd)
  ;
quit;

So if you put that list into a macro variable, let's call it DATE_LIST the code might look like:
%let date_list='03JAN2023'd '04MAY2023'd;

Which can be used to build the IN expression like this:
enddate in (&datelist)

If you have the list of dates in a dataset then you don't need a macro variable at all as the IN operator in SQL can use a list generated by a subquery.
... where enddate in (select enddate from DATES) ...

If you do need to make a macro variable from a dataset with a list of values you can use PROC SQL to generate the macro variable.  In that case it is probably going to be easier to just put the raw integer values used by SAS to store the dates into the macro variable.  No need to make them look good for humans.
proc sql noprint;
select enddate format=5. into :date_list separated by ' ' from DATES;
create table want as select * from have
  where enddate in (&date_list)
;
quit;

If you need some other syntax in the list of values (perhaps you are planning to use the values generate some SQL to run in a foreign database that has its own way of representing date literals) then just do that as part of the query that generates the macro variable.
 select quote(put(enddate,yymmdd10.),"'") 
   into :date_list separated by ',' from DATES
 ;

Now DATELIST will have a value like:
 '2023-01-03','2023-05-04'


I have tried this code in to generate the macro date field &date_list and used it in my  code instead of the date . It throws error : Teradata prepare : Syntax error, expected something  like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier  or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword or '(' between ','  and the string '2023-12-01'

Do Teradata make the values look like date '2023-03-01'
